# static variables in worker processors don't work properly?

Tags: c#, iis, static, worker-process

I have 2 servers for load balancers and each one has `8 worker processors`. I want to have a value that is shared among workers in each server. my code is like below:

```
   static string _token;
   public async Task<string> GetokenAsync()
    {
        if (token.isExpire() || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
            if (token.isExpire() || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                try
                {
                  token =  await GetTokenFromAPIServiceAsync();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _semaphoreSlim.Release();
                }
            }
            else
                _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
        return token;
    }
```

but I guess static variable does not work properly when there are many workers, because i think they `manipulate` static fileds.
so I decided to use `redis` instead of `static field` like below:

```
 public async Task<string> GetokenAsync()
    {
         var token = await GetFromRedisAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
            if (token.isExpire() || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                try
                {
                  token =  await GetFromServiceAndSetToRedisAsync();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _semaphoreSlim.Release();
                }
            }
            else
                _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
        return token;
    }
```

is it a good solution to use redis and semaphorSlim for locking threads? is semaphore working among workers or some workers might change value in redis?

Comment: If you have working code and ask for comments -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _"but I found out by these workers, static variable does not work properly "_ - can you please explain?

Comment: static works but not across processes. Your worker do not share memory so you need to put shared things in something external. What that could be is up to you.

Comment: @GuruStron static works but not across processes.

Comment: @Ralf is that correct to use singleton pattern for lock data like code no 2. or with some workers that is not a good solution?

Comment: @Neg so static works as expected but does not solve your problem inter-process information sharing?

Comment: @GuruStron i don't want all of workers get token

Comment: If multiple processes access the resource (token in redis for example) each of those accesses must be atomic (read and write/update must be inseparable). Otherwise you have racing conditions that cannot be resolved across process bounderies. For example in a SQL DB you would use transactions ...

Comment: Probably not but with the few info we have i can just guess. If you try to prevent concurrent updates of the token a simple semaphore has the same problem as using static. Its per process.

Comment: @Ralf so how can i handle to not change value?

Comment: Thats a problem that needs to be handled by the product you use for sharing you can't do anything really correct without involving that. So lookup what locking mechanisms are provided by Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is semaphore working among workers or some workers might change value in redis?

If the goal is to share information between different processes on the same server then `SemaphoreSlim` is not a solution - it works only for single app instance. For cross-process synchronization (on the same server) you need to look into using named [`Semaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-threading-semaphore-ctor(system-int32-system-int32-system-string)) or [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-threading-mutex-ctor(system-boolean-system-string)).

Alternatively you can look into mechanisms provided by Redis to perform synchronization (see [this](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/) or [this](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-2-distributed-locking/6-2-3-building-a-lock-in-redis/) for example, also it will enable option to share token between different servers if needed).

Comment: thanks, i use static field with global semaphore, and that is working